# How to test submit form with ReactiveForm. The form is reloaded during submission

Tags: angular

Everything started from the tutorial [Make Your Angular Form’s Error Messages Magically Appear.](https://netbasal.com/make-your-angular-forms-error-messages-magically-appear-1e32350b7fa5) 
There is a simple form with one input and one button. I need to invoke the submit event on a lower level to invoke another events. Because there is a directive applied to `form` The clear way is to push the button.

```
const submitBtn: HTMLElement = componentEl.querySelector('button');
submitBtn.click();
```

But the form is reloaded at the test mode only. I also tried to disable the form submission.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" controlErrorContainer (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
...
onSubmit() {
  console.log('onSubmit...');
}
```

It is not invoked. I also tried to invoke events

```
form.triggerEventHandler('submit', null);
```

and

```
form.triggerEventHandler('ngSubmit', null);
```

Change detection was started.

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```

[This is StackBlitz to test it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56258331-angular-form-submit-directive-test?file=app%2Ferror-directive.spec.ts)

Answer (score 2):

I can see 2 possible solutions:

1) using `submitBtn.click();` as you've mentioned you should add .preventDefault() call in template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" controlErrorContainer (ngSubmit)="$event.preventDefault(); onSubmit($event)">
```

or in handler:

```
onSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('onSubmit...');
  ...
}
```

OR

2) You can add some helper to use it in cases where you need to create and emit event:

```
export function createNewEvent(eventName) {
    if (typeof(Event) === 'function') {
        // not IE
        return new Event(eventName);
    } else {
        // IE
        const event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);

        return event;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
form..dispatchEvent(createNewEvent('submit'));
```

Comment: There is an interesting case that it work well on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56258331-angular-form-submit-directive-test?file=app%2Ferror-directive.spec.ts) without workaround.

Answer (score 1):

in your code I read this:

```
onSubmit() {
  console.log('onSubmit...');
}
```

but in your form you pass tha `$event` parameter. Delete `$event` parameter.

Comment: It seems that you wrote the answer that resolves my issue partly.

Comment: I have answer with ngNativeValidate but after I see the error in your code and i delete the answer

Comment: Sorry. It is little bit messy.

Comment: your don't worry it's my fault!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly why. But it works. Somebody deleted the answer that he had typed.

```
ngNativeValidate
```

Event handler are invoked these are dispatched by.

```
form.triggerEventHandler(
```